# how to create a key in HKLM using TRegistry

Tags: registry, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I am trying to create a key in HKLM but it creates under HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node! 
as C++ builder 2010 produces 32 bit exe and it saves under 32 app section
running windows 7 x64

How to use TRegistry to do it by using flags or....

in addition `OpenKeyEx` is'nt there :(

here is my code

```c
TRegistry * reg=new TRegistry(KEY_WRITE);
try 
{
  reg->RootKey=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;
  if (!reg->OpenKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\\UserList",0)) 
  {
    //reg->CreateKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\\UserList");
  }
  //reg->Access=KEY_WRITE;
  bool ores=reg->OpenKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Winlogon\\SpecialAccounts\\UserList",true);
  reg->WriteString("ouser","0");
  reg->CloseKey();
} 
catch (...) 
{
  delete reg;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to access a 64-bit Registry key from a 32-bit process.  In order to do that, you need to include the `KEY_WOW64_64KEY` flag when opening the key, eg:

```
TRegistry *reg = new TRegistry(KEY_WRITE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY);
```

Or:

```
reg->Access = KEY_WRITE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
```

In the future, if you ever upgrade to XE2 or later, which support 64-bit development, then you should specify the flag only if `IsWow64Process()` reports that you are a 32-bit process running under WOW64, eg:

```
BOOL bIsWow64 = FALSE;
IsWow64Process(GetCurrentProcess(), &bIsWow64);

long flags = KEY_WRITE;
if (bIsWow64) flags |= KEY_WOW64_64KEY;
```

.

```
TRegistry *reg = new TRegistry(flags);
```

.

```
reg->Access = flags;
```